# Perl script to replace all <h2> tags to <h1> recursively in all files

Tags: regex, linux, perl

So something like this

```
<h2 style='margin-top: 10px;'>
<?php echo $title; ?>
</h2>
```

should become

```
<h1 style='margin-top: 10px;'>
<?php echo $title; ?>
</h1>
```

---

I use this code `perl -pi -e 's/<h2(.*)<\/h2>/<h1\1<\/h1>/g' *` but it works only if tags are in one line.

Comment: [You should not parse HTML with Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/119280). Your difficulties are a perfect example of why. Use an appropriate tool for the job, e.g. an HTML parser like HTML::TreeBuilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to pair up the opening and closing tags. Simply change all opening `<h2>` tags to '` and then do the same for all closing tags. Like this

```
perl -pie 's|<h2\b|<h1|g; s|</h2\b|</h1|g;' *
```

Comment: You don't need two regexes. `s#</?h\K2#1#g`

Comment: People like my comment better than my answer, it seems.

Comment: @TLP: didn't know about `\K`. Nice and concise compared to `(?<=...)`, and the holy grail of variable-length look-behind! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pi.bak -we 's#</?h\K2#1#g' yourfile
```

`\K` will preserve matched text before it. That way we don't have to put it back after matching it.

Comment: @Devendra Update your perl version.

Comment: @Devendra The `\K` escape was introduced in v5.10. [Here’s a list of perl regex escapes by version number](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2011/11/perl-regex-escapes-by-version.html).

Answer (score 1):

No *nix environment to test, but

```
% find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -e s/\<h2/\<h1/g -e 's|</h2|</h1|g' {} \;
```

might get you started. No Perl required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl like this:

```
perl -0pe -i.bak 's#<h2(.*?)</h2>#<h1$1</h1>#gs' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open FILE, 'inputfile.txt';

my $contents = do { local $/; <FILE> };

close FILE;

$contents =~ s/<h2(.*?)<\/h2>/<h1$1<\/h1>/sg;

print $contents;
```

Note that `$/` is input record seperator.It is newline `\n` by default.
We create a localized version of `$/` so its previous value gets restored after the block finishes.